# Outlook Web Add-In - Getting and setting room for meeting in Outlook Client

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create an Outlook Web Add-In that manages meeting rooms for it's users. The problem is getting and setting rooms in the Outlook Desktop Client.

When I try to get the `item.RequiredAttendees` it gives me back the user's email eventhough the list is empty. Furthermore when I input a meeting room with an exchange address, I can't obtain the room through `item.RequiredAttendees`.

I've tried numerous things, went through the whole `office.js` API as far as I know.

To add to this, it all works fine when using `OutlookWebApp`, it returns the email with `recipientType` being `External User` as upposed to `user`. Adding only a location does not work as I need the exchange address to update the outlook calendar of that meeting room.

So, to summarize: I need a way to obtain the room email address from an outlook appointment in compose mode in the Outlook Desktop Client.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the [existing request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/15777979-add-support-in-officejs-for-complex-type-meeting-l). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]

Comment: Related to this, there is already an item on UserVoice with almost the most votes in the outlook category: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13316001-add-office-javascript-api-support-for-resources-of. For almost 2 years the status is 'In Backlog'. Several people are asking for an update on this. Why aren't we updated more often on the status of these items?